# Separate a string with SUBSTRING and PATINDEX - last step

Tags: sql-server, substring, patindex

I need to finalize a query. The query returns a column which contains values like "P100+P200" or "SUMME(P400:P1200)".

In the end, the result should be:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P100 | + | P200 |
| P400 | : | P1200 |

Solved to extract column A and column B.

I used for the first two steps this code:

```
MAX (SUBSTRING(t3.formel, PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%', t3.formel), PATINDEX('%[+:-]%', SUBSTRING(t3.formel, PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%', t3.formel), LEN(t3.formel))) - 1)) "Formelteil 1",
MAX (SUBSTRING(t3.formel, PATINDEX('%[+:.-]%', t3.formel), 1) ) AS Sonderzeichen
```

But guess I'm going to be blind about the solution for the third step.

Comment: Don't do that in SQL in the first place. SQL is a query language, not a text processing language. You *could* maybe (maybe) use regular expressions to parse these formulas but T-SQL doesn't have regular expressions. It would be very easy to parse the text in a client language like Python or C#.

Comment: It's unclear what the syntax is here too. Why is `SUMME( )` ignored for example? Are you looking for the strings around an operator like `:` or `+`? Are the operators only Latin alphanumeric characters? If you know what operators are used you could use `(?<P1>[A-Z0-0]+?)(?<Op>[:+])(?<P2>[A-Z0-0]+?)` to extract the parts as named groups, P1, Op, P2.

Comment: This ist part of a query, getting values from the Database of our ERP-System.

Comment: That's even worse, on multiple levels. First, the amount of data means the bad performance of the query will have a larger impact. If this appears in a filter you'll force a full table scan on every single operation. If you have lots of transactions, you may be scanning millions of rows each time to filter by a part of the expression. Second, it means you *can* use a client language, so there's no need to do this in T-SQL. Third, the real expressions will be far dirtier than this example.

Comment: Is part of a query, getting values from the DB ERP-System. Query is reading a (some) Schemes with n-Positions. String i'd like to spearate is just information, how the positions connected. Next steps will be (maybe) with Excel or Power-BI, my tought was also better use PHP or something else, behind all of this is a complex set of additional parameters which need to be selected (and combined) first, get the values, put them into the scheme and calculate a final value. Not each scheme is the same, can have from 3 to N-positions so i need the formula  separated to use it somewhere else.

Comment: This isn't an exaggeration. Our own ERP (one of the big 3) runs *very* slowly because some lazy implementers used some non-indexable query expressions instead of taking the time to do it right, or to cover up their bad choices. Storing categories and subcategories in a single AccountType field may have seemed a quick fix at the time but guess what happened when reports had to be made about a *specific* subcategory. And who had to clean this up

Comment: If you have Power BI, which *does* have powerful string manipulation capabilities, why are you trying SQL at all? What about SAP's own reporting features? Never mind that this looks like a SAP expression. There may be ANTLR or Python parsers for this already.

Comment: `a complex set of additional parameters which need to be selected (and combined)....` in other words, a full fat ETL job. You can't do that with ad-hoc queries. The complexity of the entire project will be high enough that you *must* avoid complex and slow quick-fixes as much as possible. Once you have 100 such quick fixes, you won't be able to understand *any* of them

Comment: `PHP or something else` PHP is completely unsuitable for this. The "something else" is Python along with Pandas or Polars dataframes. There are several ETL frameworks in Python already and both SAP and Power BI can use it directly. You can even use it in T-SQL, through `sp_execute_external_script` if you enable Python Services. You can pas query results into the script as a dataframe, use regular expressions to extract the parts in new columns then return the entire data frame as a result set

Comment: Finally, the Query: 18 row(s) fetched - 100ms (14ms fetch)

Comment: Well, it's not SAP, and my job ist actually just to perpare the result for further use. in our ERP there are - some - parts presenting data slow, because of views in queries etc. all based on Java. If i had to do thce complete Job, i'd do it also in another way, but this is not my decision... ;)

Comment: And we connect Power-BI directly to the Database with this Queries. So i have one for the Schemes, some other Queries for all other Values i need. Each of them are straight, easy and fast. there is no need to combine them in SQL, this will be done on another Level.

Comment: No data engineer or DBA would use `straight, easy and fast` for that expression. You can easily use Python as [a Transformation step in Power BI's query editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-in-query-editor) and use `([A-Z\d]+)([+:.-])([A-Z\d]+)` to extract the parts with Pandas' `str.extract`. If you name the groups you'll get new columns with those names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not really a job for SQL Server.

When asking questions like this it's helpful to provide example DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (formel NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Table (formel) VALUES 
('P100+P200'), ('G100/G200'), ('a100*z200'), ('P1005-P2005'), ('SUMME(P400:P1200)');
```

You're two thirds of the way there. Since we only seem to need to worry about one additional character, we can simply use the position of the operator + 1 to find the start of the last string and use an arbitrary number higher than the remaining characters, and then replace it with nothing:

```
SELECT t3.formel, 
SUBSTRING(t3.formel, PATINDEX('%[A-Z|a-z][0-9]%', t3.formel),PATINDEX('%[-|*|/|+|:]%', t3.formel)-PATINDEX('%[A-Z|a-z][0-9]%', t3.formel)) AS a,
SUBSTRING(t3.formel, PATINDEX('%[-*/+:]%', t3.formel), 1) AS b,
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(t3.formel, PATINDEX('%[-*/+:]%', t3.formel)+1, LEN(t3.formel)),')','') AS c
  FROM @Table t3;
```

| formel | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P100+P200 | P100 | + | P200 |
| G100/G200 | G100 | / | G200 |
| a100*z200 | a100 | * | z200 |
| P1005-P2005 | P1005 | - | P2005 |
| SUMME(P400:P1200) | P400 | : | P1200 |

Comment: I never used Substring before, so on each step i have sometimes to learn from scratch how it works... and if it works for the solution. Would be easier if i could spent more time for queries, but it's just a small part of my job. Thank you!

Comment: quick notes on `SUBSTRING`. Accepts three parameters: String - the string you'd like to make a sub-string of. Start - the index of the start of the sub-string. Length - the number of characters the substring should take. `SELECT SUBSTRING('1234567890', 2, 5)` returns 23456 - 1**23456**7890 is the string starting at 2, and continuing for 5.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score -2):

T-SQL isn't a text manipulation language and doesn't even have regular expressions. It's a lot easier to do this task in a client language, using a regular expression like `([A-Z\d]+)([+:.-])([A-Z\d]+)` to capture the three parts.

In the comments you mention the data is used in Power BI. You can use [a Python Transformation in the Query editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-in-query-editor) to apply a regular expression to the data using [Pandas' str.exact](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and automatically extract the parts into columns.

The Power BI step script is essentially a one-liner

```
import pandas as pd
pattern=r"([A-Z\d]+)([+:.-])([A-Z\d]+)"
dataset[['a','b','c']]=dataset['formel'].str.extract(pattern)
```

[str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) applies the regular expression to all the values of the `formel` column (Series) and extracts each capture group into a separate column. `dataset[['a','b','c']]=` stores those columns in the original dataset using the names `a`, `b` and `c`.

You can easily test Python scripts in the command line or a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code.

The following script, in either Python or VS Code :

```
import pandas as pd
dataset=pd.DataFrame({'formel':['P100+P400','SUMME(P200:P300)']})

pattern=r"([A-Z\d]+)([+:.-])([A-Z\d]+)"
dataset[['a','b','c']]=dataset['formel'].str.extract(pattern)
dataset
```

Prints

```
             formel     a  b     c
0         P100+P400  P100  +  P400
1  SUMME(P200:P300)  P200  :  P300
```